# jQuery UI slider change display text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I would like to change two things, in how jQuery UI slider text look, i wonder if its possible.

i would like it to look like: http://i56.tinypic.com/dm8ahi.jpg

I could like to change the color of the field, so only the slider numbers have a color(so the text will have other color).

And put a separator for the bigger numbers, to show like 1,000,000 instead of 1000000.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI slider has a 'slide' event which provides the values you need (ui). Use the UI variable to insert the value into the page, then use CSS to style the text as you want.

Read more at http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: thank, i made that part works.
its possible put the separator for that big number?